# What is the difference between these functions?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

1. $f_1:X\to Y$, $U\subseteq X$ is open, if $f_1(U)\subseteq Y$ is open.
2. $f_2:X\to Y$, if $U\subseteq X$ is open, $f_2(U)\subseteq Y$ is open.
3. $f_3:X\to Y$, $V\subseteq Y$ is open, if $f_3^{-1}(V)\subseteq Y$ is open.
4. $f_4:X\to Y$, if $V\subseteq Y$ is open, $f_4^{-1}(V)\subseteq Y$ is open.

Are there any examples to tell the differences among them?

Comment: Some suggestions: A constant function.  An inclusion map of a closed subset.

Comment: What have you done so far? What is the usual description of a function satisfying 4? Can you think of such a function which does not satisfy 1?

Answer (score 1):

1. Let $X\subseteq Y$ with subspace topology, and $f_1:X\hookrightarrow Y$ the inclusion map.
2. Let $f_2$ be an open function between topological space: $X\subseteq Y$ is open with subspace topology, and $f_2:X\hookrightarrow Y$ the inclusion map.
3. $f_3$ any continuous function between topological spaces.
4. Let $f_4$ be the projection $A\times Y\to Y$ where $A\times Y$ is endowed with product topology.